# how can I detect the height of the home indicator of an ios device?

Tags: javascript, css

At the end is that black bar (below my pagination, black bar centered),

[image]

I think it's called `home indicator`, how can I know its height so that my content is never below it and put a `margin-bottom` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `env(safe-area-inset-bottom)` for this purpose. For instance, you could apply a padding like this:

```
.my-footer {
  padding: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```

You can also use fallback values. For instance, if you would like a default padding of 10px in case `safe-area-inset-bottom` is not defined, then you can use the following:

```
.my-footer {
  padding: env(safe-area-inset-bottom, 10px);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env